# Not uniform argument order in backbone event triggers. How can I work around it?

Tags: events, backbone.js

```
someModel.bind("all", function(eventName, model, XXXXX, YYYYY) {
   options.myStuff = "MyStuff et all";
   self.trigger(eventName, model, ??????, ?????);
}
```

XXXXX, YYYYY, ????? mark the problem: Where are the options?

I want to augment the options and retrigger any event on a new context. The problem is that backbone puts options in 4th position in some events ("change:xxx", "error", etc..) and in 3rd position in some others("change", "reset") making it impossible for me to know where in the arguments the options are, and to know where in the trigger i should put the enhanced options. Is there any other way except the obvious separate snippet for every individual event?

UPDATE: Looking at the backbone source, an acceptable solution for me would be to patch Backbone to always include a third argument in every event, so that options are always in the same 4th position. It is a simple change but I am kind of hoping for a more user space solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the options are always the last argument passed to the callback. You could use the `arguments` object of the callback to modify the options. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

For example

```
var x=new Backbone.Model();
x.bind("all", function(e) {
    console.log("x : "+e);
    console.log(arguments[arguments.length-1]);
});

var m=new Backbone.Model( {name:"a"} );
m.bind("all",function(e){
    console.log("m : "+e);
    var args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    args[args.length-1].modified=true;
    x.trigger.apply(x,args);
});

m.set({name:"b"});
```